# Set a different custom provider oauth scope depending on user role with devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, oauth-2.0, doorkeeper

I'm providing [API users with an OmniAuth strategy according to the doorkeeper docs](https://github.com/doorkeeper-gem/doorkeeper/wiki/Create-a-OmniAuth-strategy-for-your-provider).  It's to allow certain users of the client application write/edit permissions on the APi.  The [doorkeeper wiki on using scopes](https://github.com/doorkeeper-gem/doorkeeper/wiki/Using-Scopes) says if your client application is requesting an authorization URI, you do something like the following:

```
http://provider.example.com/oauth/authorize?(... other params... )&scope=public+write
```

where public, write are scopes (e.g., for public access and write access).

It seems like the way to do it would be during the setup method below of the OmniauthCallbacksController

```
class Users::OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController
  def provider
    # You need to implement the method below in your model (e.g. app/models/user.rb)
    ##Some code
  end

  def setup

    render :text => "Setup complete.", :status => 404
  end
end
```

During the setup method, request.env can look like this and it passes the scope parameter correctly (note: I added the "scope" param below via the command line debugger)

```
 #   request.env['omniauth.strategy'].options
    # => {"setup"=>true,
    #  "skip_info"=>false,
    #  "client_id"=>
    #   "***",
    #  "client_secret"=>
    #   "***",
    #  "client_options"=>
    #   {"site"=>"http://localhost:3000/", "authorize_url"=>"/oauth/authorize"},
    #  "authorize_params"=>{},
    #  "authorize_options"=>[:scope],
    #  "token_params"=>{},
    #  "token_options"=>[],
    #  "auth_token_params"=>{},
    #  "provider_ignores_state"=>false,
    #  "name"=>:datafeed,
    #  "scope"=>:write}
```

But I want to be able to something like this:

```
request.env['omniauth.strategy']['scope']=:write if current_user.role=="admin"
```

But current_user is not defined by Devise at this point (and nowhere do I see a user id)...any ideas on how to figure out the user at some point in the authorization process so I can pass along the correct scope to the API?

Comment: Having kind of the same issue right now. Were you able to find a solution? Thanks!